# How to set which graphics card is used by OpenGL render active viewport?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, opengl

I whan to use 3D View OpenGL render with Blender Render.
I have a laptop with two graphics card.

[image]

Of course the NVIDIA card is the superior. I used the Blender Help / Save System Info to check the OpenGL settings. It shows like this:

[image]

Does it mean Blender using the (lame) Intel card instead of the NVIDIA card?
Is it possible to switch to the NVIDIA?

It seems there is no option in the User Preferences window to select graphics card for OpenGL. There is only graphics card option for Cycles Compute Device but as far as I know Cycles has nothing to do with OpenGL.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to discretely specify a card for drawing in Blender, it will use whichever is currently used by the system to draw on the active display.

Comment: as above, but I think you can disable the unwanted card at operating system level... it should be a right-click option  on the card icon, in the first screenshot. never tried but it could work.

Comment: This Looks like standard Optimus setting, which means the os chooses on it's own which of the two to use. When you run an application like blender, on Windows this automatically uses the NVidia card. On linux you'd need to mess with either NVidia prime or bumblebee. But on Windows, as said, the Os chooses based on application demand.

Comment: More likely you don't want to disable the unwanted card. I did it and the screen turned to black. I had to restart my computer. According to that description resource [link](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-components/how-set-default-graphics-card-3612668/) there is kind of a power management between the two GPU. So I can choose the GPU for Blender via NVidia control panel. However I did it before (as far as I remember). But I updated the NVidia driver and it is solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this article: [How to set a default graphics card](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-components/how-set-default-graphics-card-3612668/)
you can choose graphics card for an application via NVidia Control Panel. You can find it by right-clicking on your desktop.

You may need to update your NVidia driver (and restart your computer). If everything is OK, Blender system info file will look like this:

[image]

Comment: How to open two instance of blender and have open gl viewport render on different cards ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: I don't think so.