# Blender using wrong GPU for 3D View (This is not about Rendering)

Tags: gpu

I'm using two graphic cards in my system. I have recently replaced an old AMD gpu with a GT 710. Now blender is using the GT 710 instead of the much more powerful GTX 760. Blender now is painfullly slow and already stutters at 100k verts.

[image]

Anybody knows how I can choose what GPU Blender should run on?

### Blender GPU settings as requested:

[image]

### EDIT

All my programs start in Monitor 1. Blender starts in Monitor 4. Don't know why, but they are all connected to the GTC 760

[image]

Comment: You should be able to use them both.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/is-it-possible-to-use-different-cuda-capable-graphic-cards-to-render-simultaneou

Comment: Possibly similar to : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76740/how-to-set-which-graphics-card-is-used-by-opengl-render-active-viewport

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and post an image showing the GPU settings in blender's user preferences.

Comment: Viewport uses your system's primary GPU, the same your OS uses. The setting is probably inside Bios.

Comment: Blender & Substance Painter are the only programs that use the GT 710. All other programs (Photoshop, Unity, Games) use the GTX 760

Comment: What card are the monitors connected to?

Comment: Use the Nvidia control panel. You can set what GPU gets used for specific applications.

Comment: Monitors are connected to both gpu's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is control which GPU the OpenGL context is created on. Luckily the latest Nvidia Driver has a way to do that.

Open the Nvidia Control Panel, and navigate to this setting:
[image]

Comment: Since this: https://superuser.com/questions/1294720/windows-10-set-default-gpu is pretty much a duplicate of the current Question, feel free to post the same answer over there and collect the 2nd bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your primary monitor attached to the GT 710 then Blender (and any program creating an OpenGL context) will be using that instead. Make sure that the GTX 760 is set to drive your primary monitor.

If you have only one monitor attached to your machine, make sure it is attached to the GTX 760.

If you have multiple monitors attached to your machine, make sure at least one is attached to the GTX 760, and make sure that this display is set to be your primary display.

To change the primary display right-click on the desktop and select Display Settings
[image: display settings in desktop context menu]

Note though that when you set the GTX 760 as your primary display adapter **and** you use it as your Cycles compute device you will run into stuttering display for entire Windows while rendering.

Comment: I have done all that. I have edited my answer. See: https://superuser.com/questions/1294720/windows-10-set-default-gpu Sorry to be stretching this out to two questions and making such a mess. Didn't expect this to get so complicated

Answer (score 0):

I would try this http://www.nvidia.com/object/performance_group.html

I've never used it but it looks like it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many different factors that can be contributing to this problem, I highly recommend changing your default graphics card in the Nvidia control panel. If you right click on the desktop, you can access it there. Go to "Manage 3D Settings" on the left side, choose the "Program Settings" tab in that window, and select Blender (or other programs you're having issues with, too" and change the settings in the drop-down box below it to "High Performance Nvidia Processor."

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch place on the two GPU, the problem is most likely that the GT 710 do have a lower address value and blender find it before the 760. If that isn't enough it might help reinstalling them and in the worst case you can try to uninstall the 710 and hope that blender prefer a GPU with Nvidia/AMD drivers.

If you are really unlucky it can be that the serial number or address name is screwing with it and can't be solved without editing the code.

I'm more or less 100% on that it is a problem caused by the address name because the GT 710 is GPU 0 in task manager and is more likely to be used than GPU 1.

I have actually never had this problem but the solution is to make the better GPU the one with a lower number.

(You might be stuck with how it is depending on what motherboard you have and how windows react on changes, it is possible that windows will keep calling the 710, GPU 0 because it is registered as it once)

Comment: I have a PCIEx16 slot and a PCIEx4 slot. The 710 uses one lane, the GTX760 uses 8 lanes. It would be daft to switch them. Also, it is only 2 programs that access the 710 instead of the GTX760. All other programs, including games, run on the GTX760